# Boost interprocess mutex crashes instead of waiting on a lock?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-interprocess, boost-mutex

I've been at this for quite a few days (even [posted](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/interprocess-Interprocess-mutex-not-working-throwing-exception-when-trying-to-write-lock-td4680985.html#a4681056) on the boost forum) and being able to make a second process recognize a locked mutex just doesn't seem to work. Please help. This is the code:

**A common header file: SharedObject.hpp**

```
#ifndef SHAREDOBJECT_HPP 
#define SHAREDOBJECT_HPP 
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/interprocess/mapped_region.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/containers/list.hpp>
#include <time.h>//for sleep 
//--------for mutexes 
#include <boost/interprocess/mapped_region.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/shared_memory_object.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/sync/interprocess_upgradable_mutex.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/sync/scoped_lock.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/sync/sharable_lock.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/sync/upgradable_lock.hpp>

#define MUTEX_SHARED_MEMORY_NAME "NavSharedMemoryMutex" 
#define DATAOUTPUT "OutputFromObject" 
#define INITIAL_MEM 650000 
using namespace std; 
namespace bip = boost::interprocess; 

class SharedMutex 
{ 
private: 
    typedef bip::interprocess_upgradable_mutex upgradable_mutex_type; 
    mutable upgradable_mutex_type mutex; 
    volatile int counter;     
public: 
    void lockWithReadLock() const { bip::sharable_lock<upgradable_mutex_type> lock(mutex); } 
    void lockWithWriteLock() { bip::scoped_lock<upgradable_mutex_type> lock(mutex); } 
}; 

//-------------------------------------- SharedMemoryObject 
class SharedObject 
{ 
public: 
    SharedMutex* sharedMutex;   
}; 

typedef bip::allocator<SharedObject, bip::managed_shared_memory::segment_manager> ShmemAllocator; 
typedef bip::list<SharedObject, ShmemAllocator> SharedMemData; 

#endif /* SHAREDOBJECT_HPP */
```

**This is the first program:**

```
#include "SharedObject.hpp" 

int main() 
{ 
    //-----------Create shared memory and put shared object into it 
    bip::managed_shared_memory* seg; 
    SharedMemData *sharedMemOutputList; 
    bip::shared_memory_object::remove(DATAOUTPUT); 
    seg = new bip::managed_shared_memory(bip::create_only, DATAOUTPUT, INITIAL_MEM); 
    const ShmemAllocator alloc_inst(seg->get_segment_manager()); 
    sharedMemOutputList = seg->construct<SharedMemData>("TrackOutput")(alloc_inst); 

    std::size_t beforeAllocation = seg->get_free_memory(); 
    std::cout<<"\nBefore allocation = "<< beforeAllocation <<"\n"; 
    SharedObject temp; 
    sharedMemOutputList->push_back(temp); 


    //-------------------Create a shared memory for holding a mutex 
    bip::shared_memory_object::remove(MUTEX_SHARED_MEMORY_NAME);//BUG: If another program also removes this, then there won't be any shared memory remaining. This problem has to be handled better. This is not the right way to deal with shared mutexes. 
    bip::shared_memory_object shm(bip::create_only, MUTEX_SHARED_MEMORY_NAME, bip::read_write); 
    shm.truncate(sizeof (SharedMutex)); //Allocate memory in shared memory for the mutex 
    bip::mapped_region region(shm, bip::read_write); // Map the whole shared memory into this process.         
    new (region.get_address()) SharedMutex; // Construct the SharedMutex using placement new 
    temp.sharedMutex = static_cast<SharedMutex *> (region.get_address()); //Store the mutex object address for future reference 

    { 
        std::cout<<"Program 1: Before first locking -------------------------- 1 v\n"; 
        temp.sharedMutex->lockWithWriteLock(); 
        const unsigned int SLEEP_TIME_IN_SECOND = 60; 
        std::cout<<"Program 1: sleep for "<< SLEEP_TIME_IN_SECOND << "\n"; 
        sleep(SLEEP_TIME_IN_SECOND); 
        std::cout<<"Program 1: Finished sleeping\n"; 
    } 
    std::cout<<"Program 1: unlocked -------------------------------------- 1 ^\n"; 


    seg->destroy<SharedMemData>("TrackOutput"); 
    delete seg;       
    return 0; 
}//main
```

**And this is the second program:**

```
#include "SharedObject.hpp" 
#define CREATE_SEPARATE_MUTEX 

int main() 
{ 
    bip::managed_shared_memory segment(bip::open_only, DATAOUTPUT); //Open the managed segment 

    SharedMemData* sharedMemoryTrackOutputList = segment.find<SharedMemData>("TrackOutput").first; //Find the list using the c-string name 
    assert(sharedMemoryTrackOutputList);     
    std::cout << "SharedMemoryData address found at = " << (void *) sharedMemoryTrackOutputList << "\n"; 
    std::cout << "size = " << sharedMemoryTrackOutputList->size() << "\n"; 
    SharedMemData::iterator iter = sharedMemoryTrackOutputList->begin(); 

#ifndef CREATE_SEPARATE_MUTEX 
    //-------------------Create a shared memory for holding a mutex 
    bip::shared_memory_object shm(bip::open_or_create, MUTEX_SHARED_MEMORY_NAME, bip::read_write); 
    shm.truncate(sizeof (SharedMutex)); //Allocate memory in shared memory for the mutex 
    bip::mapped_region region(shm, bip::read_write); // Map the whole shared memory into this process.         
    new (region.get_address()) SharedMutex; // Construct the SharedMutex using placement new 
    (*iter).sharedMutex = static_cast<SharedMutex *> (region.get_address()); //Store the mutex object address for future reference 
#endif 

    { 
        std::cout<<"Program 2: Before first locking -------------------------- 1 v\n"; 
        (*iter).sharedMutex->lockWithWriteLock(); 
        const unsigned int SLEEP_TIME_IN_SECOND = 1; 
        std::cout<<"Program 2: sleep for "<< SLEEP_TIME_IN_SECOND << "\n"; 
        sleep(SLEEP_TIME_IN_SECOND); 
        std::cout<<"Program 2: Finished sleeping\n"; 
    } 
    std::cout<<"Program 2: unlocked -------------------------------------- 1 ^\n";     

    return 0; 
}//main
```

---

Program 1 works fine.
Program 2 gives this output:

```
SharedMemoryData address found at = 0x7f0a4c2b8118 
size = 1 
Program 2: Before first locking -------------------------- 1 v 
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::interprocess::lock_exception' 
  what():  boost::interprocess::lock_exception 
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I'm running program1 first, which locks the mutex and keeps it locked for 60 seconds. During that time I run program 2 to see if it waits on the lock, but it crashes. How can I make program 2 wait on the mutex until program 1 has finished writing to shared memory?

Comment: erm "This post has NOT been accepted by the mailing list yet." - so it looks like you didn't actually post anything to the boost mailing list. You have to be a member first.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, here are some problems with your code.

1. The `SharedMutex` is stored in a different memory region, which is not mapped in the second program.
2. The mapped region can have a different base address, so raw pointers will not work in this environment. Use [`boost::interprocess::offset_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/interprocess/offset_ptr.html) instead. Note, however, that those work for pointers to the same memory segment, so it would make sense to put your SharedMutex and SharedObject in the same segment (or instead of all this, use `named_mutex`).
3. In main1, you copy `temp` to shared memory *before* modifying the member variable `sharedMutex`. You should ensure that in shared memory your pointer (`offset_ptr`-to-be) is actually valid.
4. When you try to lock with `scoped_lock` using your `lockWithWriteLock` function, the lock is unlocked immediately at exit of the function. So once you fix all of the above and you get rid of the crash, you still won't get the expected output - the logic of your code should be changed.

and the code:

**sharedObject.hpp**

```
#ifndef SHAREDOBJECT_HPP 
#define SHAREDOBJECT_HPP 
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/interprocess/mapped_region.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/containers/list.hpp>
#include <time.h>//for sleep 
//--------for mutexes 
#include <boost/interprocess/mapped_region.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/shared_memory_object.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/sync/interprocess_upgradable_mutex.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/sync/scoped_lock.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/sync/sharable_lock.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/sync/upgradable_lock.hpp>

#define MUTEX_SHARED_MEMORY_NAME "NavSharedMemoryMutex" 
#define DATAOUTPUT "OutputFromObject" 
#define INITIAL_MEM 650000 
using namespace std;
namespace bip = boost::interprocess;

class SharedMutex
{
public:
    typedef bip::interprocess_upgradable_mutex upgradable_mutex_type;
    mutable upgradable_mutex_type mutex;
};

//-------------------------------------- SharedMemoryObject 
class SharedObject
{
public:
    SharedMutex* sharedMutex;
};

typedef bip::allocator<SharedObject, bip::managed_shared_memory::segment_manager> ShmemAllocator;
typedef bip::list<SharedObject, ShmemAllocator> SharedMemData;

#endif /* SHAREDOBJECT_HPP */
```

**Program1:**

```
#include "SharedObject.hpp"

int main()
{
    //-----------Create shared memory and put shared object into it 
    bip::managed_shared_memory* seg;
    SharedMemData *sharedMemOutputList;
    bip::shared_memory_object::remove(DATAOUTPUT);
    seg = new bip::managed_shared_memory(bip::create_only, DATAOUTPUT, INITIAL_MEM);
    const ShmemAllocator alloc_inst(seg->get_segment_manager());
    sharedMemOutputList = seg->construct<SharedMemData>("TrackOutput")(alloc_inst);

    SharedObject temp;

    //-------------------Create a shared memory for holding a mutex 
    bip::shared_memory_object::remove(MUTEX_SHARED_MEMORY_NAME);//BUG: If another program also removes this, then there won't be any shared memory remaining. This problem has to be handled better. This is not the right way to deal with shared mutexes. 
    bip::shared_memory_object shm(bip::open_or_create, MUTEX_SHARED_MEMORY_NAME, bip::read_write);
    shm.truncate(sizeof(SharedMutex)); //Allocate memory in shared memory for the mutex 
    bip::mapped_region region(shm, bip::read_write); // Map the whole shared memory into this process.         
    new (region.get_address()) SharedMutex; // Construct the SharedMutex using placement new 
    temp.sharedMutex = static_cast<SharedMutex *> (region.get_address()); //Store the mutex object address for future reference 

    std::cout << "Region address " << region.get_address() << "\n";

    sharedMemOutputList->push_back(temp);

    //initiate scope for scoped mutex
    {
        std::cout << "Program 1: Going to do 1st locking -------------------------- 1 v\n";
        bip::scoped_lock<bip::interprocess_upgradable_mutex> lock(temp.sharedMutex->mutex);
        const unsigned int SLEEP_TIME_IN_SECOND = 10;
        std::cout<<"Program 1: locked. Now sleep for "<< SLEEP_TIME_IN_SECOND << "\n";
        sleep(SLEEP_TIME_IN_SECOND);
        std::cout << "Program 1: Finished sleeping\n";
    }
    std::cout << "Program 1: unlocked ----------------------------------------- 1 ^\n";

    //seg->destroy<SharedMemData>("TrackOutput");delete seg;
    return 0;
}//main
```

**and Program2:**

```
#include "SharedObject.hpp"
#define READ_LOCK_TESTING
#ifndef READ_LOCK_TESTING
    #define WRITE_LOCK_TESTING
#endif
int main()
{
    bip::managed_shared_memory segment(bip::open_only, DATAOUTPUT); //Open the managed segment 

    SharedMemData* sharedMemoryTrackOutputList = segment.find<SharedMemData>("TrackOutput").first; //Find the list using the c-string name 
    assert(sharedMemoryTrackOutputList);
    std::cout << "SharedMemoryData address found at = " << (void *)sharedMemoryTrackOutputList << "\n";
    std::cout << "size = " << sharedMemoryTrackOutputList->size() << "\n";
    SharedMemData::iterator iter = sharedMemoryTrackOutputList->begin();

    bip::shared_memory_object shm(bip::open_or_create, MUTEX_SHARED_MEMORY_NAME, bip::read_write);
    bip::mapped_region region(shm, bip::read_write); // Map the whole shared memory into this process.       

    std::cout << "Region address " << region.get_address() << "\n";

    //Initiate the scope for the scoped mutex
    {
        std::cout << "Program 2: Going to do 2nd locking -------------------------- 2 v\n";
        iter->sharedMutex = static_cast<SharedMutex*>(region.get_address());
#ifdef WRITE_LOCK_TESTING        
        bip::scoped_lock<bip::interprocess_upgradable_mutex> lock((*iter).sharedMutex->mutex);//write lock
#endif        
#ifdef READ_LOCK_TESTING
        bip::sharable_lock<bip::interprocess_upgradable_mutex> lock((*iter).sharedMutex->mutex);//read lock
#endif        
        const unsigned int SLEEP_TIME_IN_SECOND = 10;
        std::cout << "Program 2: locked. Now sleep for " << SLEEP_TIME_IN_SECOND << "\n";
        sleep(SLEEP_TIME_IN_SECOND);
        std::cout << "Program 2: Finished sleeping\n";
    }
    std::cout << "Program 2: unlocked ------------------------------------------ 2 ^\n";

    return 0;
}//main
```

Comment: Thank you very much Rostislav. I've tried `named_mutex` also earlier, but it didn't work. Perhaps I implemented it wrong. Actual code samples would help here, because I've tried a lot of stuff and referred the boost sample code but the locking just does not work. It was as a last resort that I posted here. Would it be possible for you to update your answer with working code? I'm sure it'll help many more programmers too.

Comment: @Nav Here's the working code. Diff it with yours and see the differences. The `offset_ptr` is not used there but I think you'll get the idea. [main1](http://pastebin.com/ANMLnT5P) [main2](http://pastebin.com/HGyxNstr) [main.h](http://pastebin.com/nfGpePmJ)

Comment: Thank you @Rostislav. Much appreciated. I've added the code into your answer. I'll also have to add some exception handling, since if the programs are run a bit out of order, it tends to crash because it can't find shared memory or an interprocess exception saying that it can't find a file or directory. I'll handle that. Your help in clearing the doubt about how to solve the locking was of great help.

Answer (score 1):

Rostislav had suggested using named mutexes, so just putting up an example of named mutexes too (although I had wanted reader writer locks, and those locks don't appear to support named mutexes...I might be wrong though).

**Program 1:**

```
#include <boost/interprocess/sync/scoped_lock.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/sync/named_mutex.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>


int main ()
{
   using namespace boost::interprocess;
   try
   {
      struct mutex_remove
      {
         mutex_remove() { named_mutex::remove("fstream_named_mutex"); }
         ~mutex_remove(){ named_mutex::remove("fstream_named_mutex"); }
      } remover;

      //Open or create the named mutex
      named_mutex mutex(open_or_create, "fstream_named_mutex");

      {
          std::cout<<"gonna lock\n";
          scoped_lock<named_mutex> lock(mutex);
          const unsigned int SLEEP_TIME_IN_SECOND = 10;
          std::cout<<"Program 1: locked. Now sleep for "<< SLEEP_TIME_IN_SECOND << "\n";
          sleep(SLEEP_TIME_IN_SECOND);
      }
      std::cout<<"unlocked\n";
   }
   catch(interprocess_exception &ex){
      std::cout << ex.what() << std::endl;
      return 1;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

**Program 2:**

```
#include <boost/interprocess/sync/scoped_lock.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/sync/named_mutex.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>


int main ()
{
   using namespace boost::interprocess;
   try{
      //Open or create the named mutex
      named_mutex mutex(open_or_create, "fstream_named_mutex");

      {
          std::cout<<"gonna lock\n";
          scoped_lock<named_mutex> lock(mutex);
          const unsigned int SLEEP_TIME_IN_SECOND = 5;
          std::cout<<"Program 2: locked. Now sleep for "<< SLEEP_TIME_IN_SECOND << "\n";
          sleep(SLEEP_TIME_IN_SECOND);
      }
   }
   catch(interprocess_exception &ex){
      std::cout << ex.what() << std::endl;
      return 1;
   }
   return 0;
}
```